# WordPress - persist user session & state across devices on local server

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, session-variables, state

**CONTEXT**

I have a WordPress & WooCommerce installation running on a local server. Users can select the items they want, customize them, etc. I want to add the ability for users to press a button and take their current state (e.g. on item #3, with options #1,#2 selected) from the current device to a second device, where they can continue the process seamlessly.

**PROBLEM**

I know that if the same user is logged into both devices, then their cart will be shared so they will have their existing selections shared across the logged in devices. However, I'm not sure how to transfer the exact state (i.e. things that have been selected by not recorded by WooCommerce) across devices.

**QUESTION**

Is a session variable that is stored within the SQL table for that user be a good solution for this or is there something more effective?